# AngularJS animation initially does not work, but after first click all is good

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have 2 forms, after loading the page, the 1st is shown and the other is hidden. When I first click Add-button, my animation that reveals the 2nd form does not work. But after the first click, I can click cancel-button and add-button again, then all works properly. How can I get this to work also for the "first click"?

If anyone are interested, I am trying to adapt from the following tutorial http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

My plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/02E8eQFHQVynK3mE1IMg?p=preview

The html is

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
  <form ng-hide="main.showNewUserForm" class="ff-toggle-animation">
    <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="main.username" size="30" placeholder="New username here">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="main.showNewUserForm=true">Add</button>
  </form>
  <form ng-show="main.showNewUserForm" class="ff-toggle-animation">
    Username:  <input type="text" id="add" ng-model="main.username" size="30" placeholder="New username here"><br>
    Full name:  <input type="text" ng-model="main.name" size="30" placeholder="Add new user full name here"><br>
    Description: <textarea id="description" rows="2" ng-model="main.description" placeholder="Add user description here"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="main.save()">Save</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="main.showNewUserForm=false">Cancel</button>
  </form>
  Some content after...
</div>
```

The JavaScript animation part looks like this:

```
app.animation('.ff-toggle-animation', function() {
  return {
    addClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {
        jQuery(element).hide(400, done);
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    },
    removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
      if(className == 'ng-hide') {

        /* remove it early so you can animate on it since
           it is not possible using element.css() to set
           a style using !important */
        element.removeClass('ng-hide'); 
        jQuery(element).show(400, done);
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: this is  a bizarre way to work with `ng-hide`. First...elements have attributes `ng-hide` to start, no class of that value which is likely why you run into it not working first time. Next...why don't you just use `ng-hide` with it's internal css animations and get rid of your jQuery?

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for taking time to answer my various questions! "Internal css animations", is that some kind of default animation, where I do not have to provide any css to have an animation, like a "default animation unless otherwise provided"? I am trying to read tutorials and api, but I have not seen this mentioned (but I may have very well missed that). If I understand you correctly, how can I trigger this animation? All examples that I see have either CSS or JavaScript provided to define the animation...

Comment: Here is a plunk where I have got rid of the animation-script and the removed the corresponding class in the html. But now it just show/hide without any animation. Maybe you could show me how this could get animated the easy way you describe? http://plnkr.co/edit/OnUuKc6ztlzMfNWPnZuf?p=preview

Comment: And regarding your comment "elements have attributes ng-hide to start, no class of that value". In API says: "The ngHide directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngHide attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the ng-hide CSS class onto the element". So there is a class called ng-hide. Or did I misunderstand what you where trying to explain to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turnes out that I had not followed the tutorial properly.

Before the line where the ng-hide is removed:

```
element.removeClass('ng-hide');
```

I need to hide the element so I can performe the animation, like this:

```
jQuery(element).hide();
```

So now the animation for the show-part looks like this:

```
removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
  if(className == 'ng-hide') {
    jQuery(element).hide();

    /* remove it early so you can animate on it since
     it is not possible using element.css() to set
     a style using !important */
    console.log(element);
    element.removeClass('ng-hide');
    jQuery(element).show(400, done);
  }
  else {
    done();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yipee! I was having the same problems but didn't read a tutorial... what was the tutorial? I was reading this... http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html.... but it doesn't mention the hide... I was trying to set the height to 0 but that didn't work :)

Comment: Hmmm I actually have forgot, but I am pretty sure it was only the yearofmoo as linked, but I do not see that there either, so maybe it where somewhere else, sorry....